# Argumentos en el SELECT de forma dinámica

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ayuda!!!
necesito pasarle los argumentos a un select, algo asi:

```
create table Persona(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  nombre varchar(200) not null,
  sexo char(1)not null
);

create procedure proc1 @campos nvarchar(max), @tabla nvarchar(max)
as
    select @campos
    from @tabla
end

exec proc1 'nombre,sexo', 'persona'
```

estoy usando sql server 2008 R2, 
no debe ser con Sql Dinamic, osea, exec('select nombre,sexo from Persona')

porfavor ya intente usando xml pero sin exitos

Comment: por favor trata de escribir una pregunta con los detalles necesarios para responderla. SQL dinámico depende fuertemente del motor y versión de base de datos que estás usando.

Comment: Has intentado hacer una consulta dinámica? como esta `DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)
SET @columnList = 'CustomerID, ContactName, City'
SET @city = '''London'''
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM customers WHERE City = ' + @city
EXEC (@sqlCommand)`

Answer (score 1):

Como te escribí en mi comentario, el modo en que se podría hacer esto es por medio de una consulta dinámica:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @campos nvarchar(max) = 'nombre,sexo,telefono'
DECLARE @tabla  nvarchar(max) = 'persona'

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @campos + ' FROM ' +  @tabla
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table persona
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key
    ,nombre varchar(200) not null
    ,sexo char(1) not null
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE proc1
@campos VARCHAR(MAX)
,@tabla VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @campos + ' FROM ' + @TABLA

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
GO

EXEC proc1 'id, nombre', 'persona'
GO
```

Comment: Hola, las respuestas de solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, agrega alguna explicación para mejorar la calidad.